Defined delay of an asynchronous signal in an FPGA
What's the proper approach to delay a signal which is routed asynchronously from an input to an output pin on an FPGA? The required delay is approximately 5ns and therefore too small to do it synchronously. I know I could use a chain of buffers but my concern is if that remains deterministic with the routing throughout the evolution of the project. I'm using a Lattice ECP5.
The reason I need this delay is that an RMII interface from a CPU is routed through the FPGA - why this is the case is another topic though. The tx path works as all signals suffer from the same delay, but I need to delay the rx path a bit.
What I tried is adding a buffer, while the buffer itself doesn't add much delay, the routing gives another 1.5ns. So I could just chain some more buffers, what I don't know for sure though is whether the resulting delay remains consistent through different builds.


Maybe there's another approach you could take.

I'd be more than happy to hear what that could be :)

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. There is no magic bullet but, if you explained what you are trying to achieve and why....

Is 5ns the total delay required? Which delay do you get if you route it directly from an input to a nearby output?

Anything between 5 and 10ns should do the job. I didn't try routing it to a nearby output, if I route it to the output it has to go, the routing delay is about 4ns, but I need additional 5ns.

Implementing delay with FPGA elements and routing will result in a delay that depends on Process, Voltage, Temperature, the phase of the moon, the rest of the stuff in the FPGA, etc.

The reason I need this delay is that an RMII interface from a CPU is routed through the FPGA
The tx path works as all signals suffer from the same delay, but I need to delay the rx path a bit.

What you can do is delay all the RX signals by one RMII clock cycle. All you need is a bunch of flops. As long as the MAC sees RX_DV and data with good timing margin relative to the clock it won't care if it's delayed by one clock cycle or two.
On the TX side, you need matching delays on all lines, so you may have to babysit the routing, add timing constraints, etc. For example I'm not sure you should use a dedicated FPGA clock line for the clock as it would then propagate faster than the data if the latter uses generic FPGA routing...
On the RX side you have to check if the timing is tighter on the receive side of the FPGA or the transmit side. Putting the flops on the receiving pins of the FPGA would give the best timing margin on this side, but worse on the MAC side as all signals still go through the FPGA. Putting the flops on the output pins of the FPGA would do the opposite.
But nothing stops you from putting flops on both sides of the FPGA and delay the signals by 2 clock cycles, so you get best timing margins on both sides and ample margin for propagation in the FPGA.
In fact if you do not want to worry about matching delays on the TX side inside the FPGA you can also resynchronize the TX signals with the clock. In this case you'll be able to use dedicated clock routing for the clock inside the FPGA, which is a much better fit for a clock signal.
From the MAC's point of view, there's no difference between a longer LAN cable adding propagation delay, or the RMII signals being delayed by a few clocks, so it's not an issue. Of course the "data_valid" signal should be in sync with the data on both sides.
Many FPGAs have flops in the IO buffers anyway, so they're free, if you're not using them they'll just sit there.

The Ref Clock signal is not on a clock input pin and therefore not routed as clock network. But this also gives me the issue that I cannot use it to clock the flops on the receiving line... or am I wrong here?

You can still do it, you'll just get a bit more skew, and the synthesis tool will complain

Yes, had to explicitely ignore the warning. Will test it and let you know if it worked out...

Can you use an external component, like a delay line?
Trying to do that with buffers internal to the FPGA is fraught with problems, the main one being that the FPGA manufacturer usually only guarantees max delay times, not minimum.  And if they do specify a minimum delay time for something like a buffer, the min to max spread is probably way to large to be able to build a reliable 5 ns delay.

Unfortunately not, the PCB already exists. I updated the question with some more detail to the problem
